# How to schedule a message in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have a Artemis' `bootstrap.xml` config file here

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema" schedulerSupport="true">

   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>    
   <server configuration="file:/opt/activemq/apache-artemis-home/etc//broker.xml"/>

   <web bind="http://10.0.34.96:8161" path="web">
       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>

</broker>
```

Even the artemis server restart, the schedule message still not work. The consumer gets the message from the `TEST` queue immediately.

```java
try { 
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://10.0.34.96:61616");

    Connection connection = factory.createConnection();

    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Create Destination queue
    Destination queue = session.createQueue("TEST");

    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

    long schedDelivery = System.currentTimeMillis() + 50000;
    String msg = "Hello World (test  SCHED_DELIVERY) "+schedDelivery;

    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
//            message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, 100000);
    message.setLongProperty("_HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", schedDelivery);
    System.out.println("Producer Sent: " + msg);
    producer.send(message);

    session.close();
    connection.close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception Occured");
}
```

Any one know how to set the `ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` or `_HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` property ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use ActiveMQMessage.setJMSDeliveryTime(schedDelivery) or maybe this will work:  message.setLongProperty("_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", schedDelivery)

Answer (score 0):

Using `_HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` with the new Artemis clients will not work. That is the old property used by/for legacy HornetQ clients. You need to use `_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY`. For convenience this property is defined in `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message` so you can use something like this.

Also, keep in mind that the scheduled delivery time is an absolute time and not a relative time.

Putting this together you can use something like this:

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message;
...
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
time += 5000;
jmsMessage.setLongProperty(Message.HDR_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_TIME.toString(), time);
```

Or you could also use something like:

```java
jmsMessage.setLongProperty("_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000);
```

ActiveMQ Artemis ships with [an example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/standard/scheduled-message) at `examples/features/standard/scheduled-message` which demonstrates all this.

You can read more about scheduled messages in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/scheduled-messages.html).

Lastly, you don't need to set `schedulerSupport="true"` in `bootstrap.xml`. That setting is strictly for ActiveMQ "Classic" and not ActiveMQ Artemis. Also, `ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` is likewise for ActiveMQ "Classic".